# SQL - Having 0 when using Count

Tags: sql, join, count

I have a list of people that have their professions listed as the following:

```
Doctor Male
Teacher  Male
Principal Male
Nurse Female
Doctor Male
```

When I group them by profession, I would like for Access to return 0 for any profession that is not in the sublist I have. Here is the code I am using:

```
SELECT Profession.Profession, Count(Profession.Profession) AS CountOfProfession
FROM People INNER JOIN Profession ON People.PeopleID = Profession.PeopleID
WHERE (((People.Sex)="Male"))
GROUP BY Profession.Profession;
```

I would like for it to yield 2 for Doctor since there are 2 males, but also yield 0 for Nurse since there are no male nurses. Please let me know how I can do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an outer join. I switched the order of the tables so it is a `left join`:

```
SELECT Profession.Profession,
       sum(iif(people.sex = "Male", 1, 0)) AS CountOfProfession
FROM Profession LEFT JOIN
     ON People.PeopleID = Profession.PeopleID 
GROUP BY Profession.Profession;
```

Comment: The `where` clause turns this into an inner join.

Comment: The condition `WHERE (((People.Sex)="Male"))` is to be omitted, I think.

Comment: I still want to know how many Males there are though. Changing this to LEFT JOIN didn't fix this as I am still missing professions that have only female as sex.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff seems you can do a count by male and then join the results with the list of professions (keeping the left join)

Comment: I fixed the query . . . My apologies, brain must not be working right today.  I do actually know how a left join works.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an outer join and moving the condition from the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT Profession.Profession, 
       COUNT(People.PeopleID) AS CountOfProfession
FROM Profession 
  LEFT JOIN People 
    ON (  People.PeopleID = Profession.PeopleID
      AND People.Sex = 'Male' )
GROUP BY Profession.Profession ;
```